# Select и Input в одном

Tags: html, javascript

Собственно сабж, возможна ли реализация оного на HTML без JS или с оным. И если несложно, натолкните на пример.

Comment: Может, есть смысл использовать <a href="http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/254/">плагин для JQuery</a>?

Comment: можно поподробней?
плагин Jquery и так для этого в даный момент используеться, но как заставить список появлятся при клике по кнопке(как в селекте) и как эту кнопку дорисовать в инпут?

пы.сы.. спасибо за ссылку, до написания коммента не заметил ее, но там немного не то. или просто еще не разобрался как работает, нужно чтобы список сокращался при вводе текста(т.е. фильтры по части текста(это реализовано))

Comment: http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/235/
http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/254/
нужно по сути обьединение данных плагинов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вставляешь кнопку после этого текстбокса потом ее position:relative; z-index:1; left:-30px;
потом в событие он клик кнопки вызываешь textbox.focus()

потом правишь jsonSuggest.js
здесь вроде проверка, убираешь этот блок (не говоришь начальнику)

if (this.value.length < settings.minCharacters) {
    $(results).html('').hide();
    return false;
}

а лучше всего посмотреть на другие autocomple для jquery или написать свой

Comment: спасиб за совет, прочел книжка по jquery, переделал компонент)

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможна. `datalist` поможет сделать гибрид input'а с select'ом.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429183/178988