# Select list option php

Tags: php, html

[image: select_option]

У меня есть выпадающий лист, с определенными значениями(из базы данных).
Вопрос: 
Как сделать если там нет значение который мне нужен, тогда я должен ввести значения сам. Например там нет красный, я должен написать там же слово красный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/datalist
http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

http://jsfiddle.net/3zdjntco/

```html
<input list="colors-list">

<datalist id="colors-list">
  <option value="Blue"></option>
  <option value="Brown"></option>
  <option value="Orange"></option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный здесь ранее способ хорош. Но, как альтернативу, я бы советовал на пользовательской стороне использовать js: это дает больше возможностей поиграться с внешним видом всего этого

Вариант а) Добавить `<option value="Custom"></option>`, при выборе которого появляется скрытое до того поле `<input name="Custom" value=""/>`, куда человек сможет ввести нужное значение (на стороне PHP, соотв. можно добавить обработку, что-то вроде `$color = ($_GET['colorlist']=="Custom")? $_GET['Custom'] : $_GET['colorlist'];`

Вариант б) Выподающий список вообще реализовать на js (например, оформив соответствующим образом список `<ul><li></li></ul>`, куда будут погружаться значения из БД), а результат выбора загонять в скрытое поле input. - тогда,  для ввода произвольного значения можно загнать хоть в само меню
(`<ul><li>Red</li><li>...</li><li><input name="Custom" value=""/></li></ul>`)

Answer (score 0):

Добавить это в меню выбора в базу, если меню тянется из базы, либо напрямую в html код, если меню тянется из самой страницы.

Comment: ))) спасибо за ответ, такой метод не катит

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, использовать такой вариант: добавить в список при выводе вариант "Отсутствует в списке", при выборе его отображать дополнительное поле для ввода, куда уже можно руками ввести любое значение.