# Выпадающий список со значениями вместо input

Tags: javascript

Имеем на странице самый обычный input. Никаких манипуляций с кодом этой формы мы проводить не можем, то есть, добавлять что либо можно только по средствам js. Нужно превратить input в выпадающий список. Картинка для понимания вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По факту, его нужно скрыть и добавить после него такой код:

```
<div class="select">
<span class="placeholder">Выберите значение</span>
<ul>
<li data-value="es">Значение 1</li>
<li data-value="en">Значение 2</li>
<li data-value="fr">Значение 3</li>
<li data-value="de">Значение 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Значения из data-value при выборе пункта должны попадать в input, а содержимое выбранного пункта списка попадать в span.

Есть скрипт, как это дело можно реализовать имея доступ к редактированию формы, прикреплю его для ознакомления, но, доступа к редактированию нет.

```js
$('.select').on('click','.placeholder',function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  if ( ! parent.hasClass('is-open')){
    parent.addClass('is-open');
    $('.select.is-open').not(parent).removeClass('is-open');
  }else{
    parent.removeClass('is-open');
  }
}).on('click','ul>li',function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  parent.removeClass('is-open').find('.placeholder').text( $(this).text() );
  parent.find('input[type=text]').attr('value', $(this).attr('data-value') );
});
```

```css
.select li {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <span class="placeholder">Выбрать язык</span>
  <ul>
    <li data-value="es">Испанский</li>
    <li data-value="en">Английский</li>
    <li data-value="fr">Французский</li>
    <li data-value="de">Немецкий</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" name="myname"/>
</div>
```

Возможно удастся просто дополнить этот скрипт. Буду признателен за любую помощь в этом вопросе. **Спасибо!**

Comment: 1. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/473861/178988 2. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429183/178988

Comment: Спасибо, но datalist не кроссбраузерное решение и внешне не настраивается так как нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

замена input на список

```js
 $(function() {
   var data = {
     div: {
       "class": "select"
     },
     span: {
       "class": "placeholder",
       text: "Выбрать язык"
     },
     li: [{
       value: "es",
       text: "Испанский"
     }, {
       value: "en",
       text: "Английский"
     }, {
       value: "fr",
       text: "Французский"
     }, {
       value: "de",
       text: "Немецкий"
     }]
   };
   $.fn.plugin = function(data) {
     return this.each(function(index,
       self) {
       self.type = "hidden";
       var span = $("<span/>", data.span);
       var ul = $("<ul/>").hide();
       var div = $("<div/>", data.div).on("click", function() {
         ul.fadeToggle("slow")
       });
       data.li.forEach(function(el) {
         var li = $("<li/>", {
           text: el.text,
           click: function() {
             self.value = el.value;
             span.text(el.text);
             $("li", ul).not(li.addClass("active")).removeClass("active")
           }
         }).appendTo(ul)
       });
       span.appendTo(div);
       ul.appendTo(div);
       $(self).replaceWith(div).appendTo(div);
       $(document).click(function(event) {
         if (!$(event.target).closest(div).length) ul.fadeOut("fast")
       })
     })
   };
   $('[name="myname"]').plugin(data)
 });
```

```css
.select {
  margin: 0;
  padding 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
li.active {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myname" />
```

Comment: Отличное решение. Спасибо большое за вашу работу.

Comment: Можно ли добавить в данный скрипт проверку value? То есть, если в input уже вписано одно из заданных значений, например, значение "en", то вместо "Выбрать язык" будет "Английский".

Answer (score 1):

Придумал решение своего вопроса. Однако, если кто-то предложит более простой и быстрый способ, буду рад обсудить. Итак, сперва нужно создать выпадающий список нужного нам вида, затем скриптом связать выбор значений из этого списка с нужным input-ом, после чего, при помощи .insertAfter, перенести этот блок к к нужному элементу. На деле все будет выглядеть так:

http://codepen.io/pen/BzRjWq

```js
$('.select').on('click','.placeholder',function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  if ( ! parent.hasClass('is-open')){
    parent.addClass('is-open');
    $('.select.is-open').not(parent).removeClass('is-open');
  }else{
    parent.removeClass('is-open');
  }
}).on('click','ul>li',function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  parent.removeClass('is-open').find('.placeholder').text( $(this).text() );
  $('input[name=myname]').attr('value', $(this).attr('data-value') );
});
$( ".select" ).insertAfter( "input[name=myname]" );
```

```css
.select .placeholder,
.select.is-open ul li {
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.select ul {
  display: none;
}

.select.is-open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="myname" value="text" />

<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
<div class="select">
  <span class="placeholder">Выбрать язык</span>
  <ul>
    <li data-value="es">Испанский</li>
    <li data-value="en">Английский</li>
    <li data-value="fr">Французский</li>
    <li data-value="de">Немецкий</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```